# Count function using defined array values

Tags: fortran

This program originally was a test program to see if I could count numbers in a specific range. Now I am making a program to do the same thing, but for 4 different columns separately (20 bins for each column b,c,d,e.) So, for column b I want 20 bins with the complete bin range going from (-3 to 3). For example, bin1 for column b will count how many numbers in that column are in the range (-3 to -2.7), bin2 would count for the range (-2.7, -2.4), etc.. I want the bin width and each bin range to be the same for each column so that each column is counted for the same ranges. Originally, I had a horribly inefficient program (which worked) but in the end I had 80 if statements (20 for each column.) I wanted to see if I could use arrays and the count function to reduce it to just 4 lines. I have seen suggestions in the comments to have an array which looks like:

```
    binb(i)=binb(i)+count(b>=lower(i) .and. b<upper(i))
    binc(i)=binc(i)+count(c>=lower(i) .and. c<upper(i))
    bind(i)=bind(i)+count(d>=lower(i) .and. d<upper(i))
    bine(i)=bine(i)+count(e>=lower(i) .and. e<upper(I))
```

but lower and upper must be arrays instead of scalars... Here is my program thus far:

```
program mean_analysis
implicit none

integer i, j, k, N, l
double precision a, b, c, d, e
integer binb(1:20),binc(1:20),bind(1:20),bine(1:20)
real lower(1:20),upper(1:20)



character(100) event

upper(1)=-2.7
lower(1)=-3








    
open(unit = 7, file="zpc_initial_momenta.dat")
    do l=2,20
        lower(l)=lower(l-1)+.3
        upper(l)=upper(l-1)+.3  
    end do
    
    do k=1, 10
        read(7,'(A)') event
        do j=1,4000
        read(7,*) a, b, c, d, e
        do i=1,20
    binb(i)=binb(i)+count(b>=lower(i:) .and. b<upper(:i))
    binc(i)=binc(i)+count(c>=lower(i:) .and. c<upper(:i))
    bind(i)=bind(i)+count(d>=lower(i:) .and. d<upper(:i))
    bine(i)=bine(i)+count(e>=lower(i:) .and. e<upper(:i))   
    
    end do
    end do
    end do
            
close(7)
        
open(unit = 8, file="outputanalysis.dat")
    Write(8,*) 'The bins in each column are as follows:'
    Write(8,*) 'FIRST COLUMN (MOMENTUM IN X DIRECTION)'
    write(8,*) binb
    
close(8)

end program
```

I have tried to remedy the lower - upper scalar issue by implementing an idea someone had on another post of mine, to make lower-> lower(I:) and upper -> upper(:I) , but it does not use the correct i-th values for the upper and lower arrays that I defined earlier with a do loop. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks vaguely like a post in Fortran discourse.  Have you thought about broadcasting to reddit r/fortran and comp.lang.fortran as well.

Comment: What do you mean by Fortran discourse?

Comment: If you want to use `count`, you need first to read the values `a, b, c, d, e` into arrays (of size 4000 in your example), and **once** the loop on j is finished you can count the elements `binb(i) = count(b(:) >=lower(i) .and. b(:)<upper(i))`. However, using `count` here just looks like a complication that you don't need. in your current code just write `if (b>=lower(i) .and. b<upper(i)) binb(i)=binb(i) + 1` (and so on...)